# Could not detect rake tasks

Tags: heroku

```
   ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
   and using the production group of your Gemfile.
   This may be intentional, if you expected rake tasks to be run
   cancel the build (CTRL+C) and fix the error then commit the fix:
   rake aborted!
```

I don't have any rake tasks that I'd like to run automatically. Should I just ignore this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try enabling user-env-compile

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

Comment: that would probably be the best solution in my case

Comment: Would be nice to provide detail about what exactly that does and why it would work.

Comment: heroku labs is deprecated

Comment: `Couldn't find that feature.`

Answer (score 5):

Effective December 05, 2013, [Heroku added debug output to deploys using the Ruby build pack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/363).

The error is triggered:

- *if the `assets:precompile` task does not exist or*
- *if there is an error in the Rakefile.*

  - *Two common causes of errors in the Rakefile are referencing a dependency not available in production (such as rspec) or*
  - *expecting an environment variable to be present.*

It's counter-intuitive because the app never runs without config vars, but [Heroku's build process executes **without** config vars](http://12factor.net/build-release-run).

As per the error message, ensure you can run `bundle exec rake -P RAILS_ENV=production` **with no environment variables present** before pushing to Heroku (e.g. comment out your environment variables while running the aforementioned command).

Also, rest assured that `rake`'s `-P` switch is harmless, so you can run it as much as you want until you fix this issue. This switch is used to *display a list of all tasks and their immediate prerequisites.* See [Rake Command Line Usage](http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/command_line_usage_rdoc.html) if you want to double-check. The output may have over `200` lines, and look something like this:

```
rake about
    environment
rake assets:clean
    environment
rake assets:clobber
    environment
rake assets:environment
rake assets:precompile
    environment
rake db:_dump
...
rake tmp:pids:clear
rake tmp:sessions:clear
rake tmp:sockets:clear
```

Comment: Also, make sure your Gemfile includes `rake`. It was as simple as that for me. Still haven't figured out why it needs it in the Gemfile now when it didn't before, though.

Comment: You should *not* need `rake` in `Gemfile`, as `rake` is a dependency of [`railties`](https://rubygems.org/gems/railties), which is a dependency of [`rails`](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails) (which is in the default group of `Gemfile`).

Comment: This may be true for Rails apps, but not other Rack apps necessarily, such as Middleman. In my case, it _did_ make sense to add `rake` to my `Gemfile`.

Comment: Roger that. I realize now that I said what I said because you said "make sure", and I didn't want that phrasing to trip up an innocent bystander.. :)

Answer (score 4):

I started getting this strange error all of a sudden yesterday. Heroku confirmed making an [update](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog) to the Ruby buildpack...

It has to do with the Rakefile. Does your Rakefile require any files? Does it require your app files? If so, then the app should not raise exceptions when it is loaded without any config vars set.

It's counter-intuitive because the app never runs without the config vars set.

In my case, the Sinatra app was looking for database urls in the init file:

```
uri = URI.parse( ENV[ "REDISTOGO_URL" ])
```

This will raise an exception if there are no env vars set.

You may have the same issue with other database URL's, such as Mongo or Postgres.

So, protect against missing env vars:

```
if  ENV[ "REDISTOGO_URL" ]
  uri = URI.parse( ENV[ "REDISTOGO_URL" ])
  ...
```

You can check if it will work before pushing to Heroku by running `bundle exec rake -P`

Also, make sure all your tests pass after updating your init. Remove any cached init state by restarting Spork or similar.

Reference: [Show Rakefile errors in Ruby deploys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/363)

Comment: Yes, I do import the app resources, and a simple conditional import would do the job here. I wonder if I could load the env or prevent heroku from checking the Rakefile.

Comment: There is a way to load the env: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile. However, I think it is easier and better to use the conditional. I don't think it is possible to prevent Heroku from checking the Rakefile...

Comment: Use of that lab feature is discouraged for security reasons. And yes, circumventing Heroku's build process is not the right way to solve this problem. But this answer, though it can send the reader on the right path, has numerous issues (e.g. preventing your app from raising an exception when there are no env vars set -- on the contrary, you want your app to explode under that circumstance). I tried to fix this answer, but then I was taking away the bulk of what was said. I thank you for your changelog reference, but with all due respect I am going to submit another answer.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I just ran into this issue also.

It turned out that I had `config.assets.css_compressor = :sass` commented out, when there was a rake task referring to it in `production.rb`.

Very simple oversight, but that would cause `rake assets:precompile` to fail and thus cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I ran into this issue just now, and there is a new fix for it.  If you're using Ruby version <= 2.6.1, and Bundler 2.0.1, update Ruby to 2.6.3 (`$ rvm install "ruby-2.6.3"`) and Bundler to 2.0.2 (`$ gem install bundler '2.0.2'`).  Make sure to specify the new Ruby version in your Gemfile.

Unfortunately I can't tell you why this works, but it's worked for 3 other people on my team so far, so it's worth a shot.