# Deploying Rails 4.1 in a subdirectory to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, asset-pipeline, buildpack

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
my-app/
  .git/
  db/    <-- Database stuff
  lib/   <-- Business logic
  spec/
  web/   <-- Rails
```

Rails is in the `web/` subdirectory of the repository. Heroku doesn't like this by default.

I have a [partially working heroku buildpack](http://github.com/makersquare/heroku-buildpack-ruby). It basically calls `Dir.chdir` to change into the `APP_SUBDIR` environment variable (if it exists) before running any tasks.

I'd like to deploy to Heroku, but I can't get the asset pipeline task to work. When it comes time to precompile assets, the customized buildpack changes to the `web/` directory and attempts to run the task.

However, [I get this error](http://pastie.org/9167419), with the following important bit:

```
Could not detect rake tasks
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
Your Ruby version is 1.9.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

Which is weird since Heroku clearly says I'm running 2.0 in that very same pastie. In fact, when I run:

```
$ heroku run 'cd web; bundle exec rake -P'
```

it work just fine.

**TL;DR (Summary)**

Heroku thinks my ruby version is `1.9.2` when it's really the `2.0.0` [shown in its own build process](http://pastie.org/9167419). Why might this be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not detect rake tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422629/could-not-detect-rake-tasks)

Comment: Was going to recommend changing your buildpack, but seems you have done this!

Answer (score -1):

You can push only the subdirectory the Rails app lives in to Heroku:

```
git subtree push --prefix web heroku master
```

Where `web` is the subdirectory.