# Trying to deploy Sinatra app to Heroku with psql database, getting load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm not the most experienced of developers so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

I am trying to deploy a Sinatra app that uses PostgreSQL as it's database. My application works locally but then when I try to deploy to Heroku, I get this error:

[Screenshot of Terminal after I try to push to heroku master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCIJH.png)

I have no idea what is going on. I don't think I'm requiring anything incorrectly b/c I would think that it wouldn't work locally if that were the case. I tried running the bit of code that says "bundle exec rake -P" but it didn't do anything as far as I know. I thought maybe I'd have to create a database and migrate it since I did that with a Rails app I was working on, but this is in Sinatra, so not sure if you have to do something entirely different.

It apparently deployed to Heroku, but when I run heroku open, it doesn't work. I just get a page that says to try again later and look at the log.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how heroku works, but in your Gemfile, do you have `gem 'pg'` in your `production` group?

Comment: even better, do you have `gem 'datamapper'` within the `production` group (or actually outside your `development` group)

Comment: @JoshPurvis I didn't before but I put it in earlier as a friend suggested and it's still not working :/

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn I have one test group and everything else falls outside of it (including data_mapper)

Comment: did you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422629/could-not-detect-rake-tasks

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn yeah I think that was one of the first things I tried but unless I did that wrong, it also didn't work, unfortunately

Comment: Thanks everyone who helped, the issue was sorted finally! I think it was a combination of having added gem 'pg' and running heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql. Then there was a separate issue where I was requiring factory girl where I shouldn't have been.